# post-review: Send specific commits under different packages to review

Tags: git

I am using post-review to send the files for review.
Lets say I have package A, under which there are 10 files `a[1], a[2], a[3], ..., a[10]` under src folder.: `A/src/a[i]`. I am working under **"branch-a"**.  To send say `a[1], a[2]`. Say I have also committed with sha: `a123`.

Lets say I also have another package B which has another 10 files `b[1], b[2], b[3], .. , b[10]`. under same src folder: `B/src/b[i]`. I am working under **"branch-b"**. To send say `b[1], b[2] and b[3]`. Say I have also committed with sha: `b123`.

**Note:** These **10+10** files are newly made or newly modified.

Now I want to send these all `a[1], a[2], b[1], b[2] and b[3]` all together under the same post-review.

A detailed explanation with the commands will be helpful. I tried reading the post-review documentation but not able find a solution for such situations.

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should create two separate commits, one for each package.

Then you can use: `--revision-range=sha`. Eg. for your scenario:

```
post-review --revision-range=a123

post-review --revision-range=b123
```

If a review should have more then one commit, you can use the general form:

```
post-review --revision-range=sha1:sha2
```

This will create one review request for everything between sha1 and sha2 (including sha1 and sha2).

But if you specify only one revision (eg. a123 in your case) only the changes from that commit will be included.

Or, if you do not have the commits ready you can create two diff files and use: `post-review --diff-filename=mycode.diff` approach. Check the [docs](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.5/users/tools/post-review/) for more details.

Comment: Well, don't you think 'post-review --revision-range=<x>', <x>: a123, b123 will two create two separate post-review ids. I actually want them in single post-review id. I am not sure about how git works... but can this be a solution: 'post-review --revision-range:a123:b123', if I commit a123 first, and both commits are done in different package?

Comment: @shukas1995 Yes, if you need them in a single review you can use `--revision-range=a123:b123` approach